# Stop execution if case of type hint discrepancy

Tags: python, pycharm

**Python 3.8**

**Pycharm Community 2020.3**

I'm trying to learn how to use type hints in Pycharm. I want Pycharm to stop execution and show me an error message in case of type discrepancy.

So, the type hint severity is "Error". Why has Pycharm not stopped at runtyme and has not showed me an error message?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Type enforcement is a declared non-goal of type annotations. Also error notifications in the IDE are no runtime errors. They have no influence in the running code.

Comment: The IDE isn't going to stop Python *at runtime* based on type hints. Generally, you must use third-party static analysis, which an IDE like PyCharm *does* use, or a library like `mypy`. For runtime validation, other libraries exist, e.g. `pydantic`